# Calculating the t-score from a p-value in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a p-value of 0.005 and a df = 120

I want to calculate bilateral t-scores in python, similar to the R command: T1 = qt(0.005, 120) and T2 = -qt(0.005, 120).

I have tried to understand whats happening in the https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nct.html#scipy.stats.nct but i cannot figure it out. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use .ppf within scipy.stats.nct

Example:

```
T1 = scipy.stats.nct.ppf(0.005, 120)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not work, as scipy.stats.nct.ppf requires a noncentrality parameter. However you can use [scipy.stats.t.ppf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html#scipy.stats.t): `T1 = scipy.stats.t.ppf(0.005, 120)`.